# Qt show() on 2nd form after hide() and close() of 3rd form doesnt work,

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

i have a weird problem,  i need to hide a form(form2) before i exec() a new dialog(form 3), and immediately after exec returns on close of that dialog(form 3), i call this->show on the form 2. But the form 2 never shows and i get the form 1 on closing form 3. 
i hv also noticed that replacing exec() calls to form 2 and 3   by show() and creating the child dialogs on the heap , does not hide form 1 and 2 respectively when form 2 n 3 shows , they stay visible though... Please please let me know if anybody knows what i am missing.﻿ below is a part of the code
method 1 (this returns to form 1 on closing form 3 with close())

```
form3 f3;
this->hide();
f3.exec();
this->show();
 method 2 (this never hides from 2 but returns to form 2 on closing form3 with close())


 f3=new Menu(this);
 this->hide();
 f3->show();
 this->show();
```